Unable to make kubectl pods comunnicate
I have a laravel application that needs to comunnicate with mysql, and I also have phpmyadmin to look at the db, but I always get connection refused. Here are the codes:
.env (only the part that I think is relevant):
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=laravel-container
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_electron
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

configmap.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db-config
  labels:
    app: mysql
data:
  DB_NAME: laravel_electron
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DB_PASSWORD: root
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

php.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: php
  labels:
    app: php 
spec:
  containers:
  - name: phpmy
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: php
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80 
    protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort

sql.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "512Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3306
    envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: db-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    protocol: TCP
  type: ClusterIP

and lastly laravel.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: laravel-container
  labels:
    app: laravel-container
spec:
  containers:
  - name: laravel-container
    image: projeto_app-main-laravel_app
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: laravel-container
spec:
  selector:
    app: laravel-container
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000 
    protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort

I know I don't need kubernetes to do this, but my professor has this as a requirement of the project
When I try to migrate seed in the laravel container it doesn't work and I'm unable to log in on phpmyadmin

Does DB_HOST need to be set to the name of the database's Service, mysql?  You also might need some additional settings to cause the mysql image to create the database with the name you want.  You should generally avoid creating bare Pods; create a StatefulSet for the database (with its associated storage) and Deployments for the application and database admin tool.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
